# Convolution with the heat kernel

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, stochastic-processes

One finds in Ikeda and Watanabe (Stochastic Differential equations and Diffusion processes- page 172) the following construction:

$$g_t(x) = (2\pi t)^{-d/2} \exp \bigg(- \frac{|x|^2}{2t}\bigg)\\
 v_\lambda(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x)\, dt$$

for $x \in \Bbb{R}^d$ $t,\lambda >0$.

Define now

$$V_\lambda f (x) = v_\lambda * f (x) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} v_\lambda (x-y) f(y)\, dy  =\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,f(y)\, dy  $$

**Question:** Now consider $h \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^d)$ then

$$ \lambda V_\lambda h - \frac{1}{2}\Delta V_\lambda h  = h $$

**Ideas:** One can consider

$$ \lambda V_\lambda h - \frac{1}{2}\Delta V_\lambda h  = \\
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy = \\ 
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\bigg(\int_\epsilon^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy  = \\
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}e^{-\lambda \epsilon} g_\epsilon (x-y)h(y)\, dy = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (g_\epsilon * h) (x) = h(x)  $$

I understand that
$$\int_\epsilon^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt  = \int_\epsilon^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) \, dt  - \int_\epsilon^\infty  e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt  \\ 
= \int_\epsilon^\infty  \partial_t\bigg(-  e^{-\lambda t}\bigg) g_t(x-y) \, dt  - \int_\epsilon^\infty  e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \\= 
e^{-\lambda \epsilon}g_\epsilon(x-y) + \int_\epsilon^\infty e^{-\lambda t} \partial_t g_t(x-y) \, dt  - \int_\epsilon^\infty  e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt =e^{-\lambda \epsilon}g_\epsilon(x-y) $$

What I can't justify is how we make the passage

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy = \\ 
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\bigg(\int_\epsilon^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy $$

It seems to me that this is not allowed since there is a singularity at $x- y = 0$.

Can we make such passage?

Do we need the term $e^{-\lambda t}$ to make this?

If not then why do we introduce this factor $e^{-\lambda t}$?

Comment: 1. How will singularity at $x = y$ affect the integral? 2. You can consider the difference, which contains $\int_0^\epsilon$, and try to argue that it vanishes. Should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy = \\ 
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_\epsilon^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy   + \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\epsilon \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy \\
= e^{-\lambda \epsilon}g_\epsilon(x-y) + \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\epsilon \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy \\
$$

Now we estimate the term $\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\epsilon \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy$
\begin{align*}
&\bigg|\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\epsilon \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy \bigg|\\
&\leq  \int_0^\epsilon \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg| \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y) h(y)\, dy \bigg|\, dt  \\
&\leq \epsilon\lambda \|h\|_\infty + \epsilon\sup_{t \leq \epsilon}\|\Delta g_t\|_1 \|h\|_\infty \xrightarrow[\epsilon \to 0]{} 0
\end{align*}

Another way to see this is to note that 
$$ \lambda V_\lambda h - \frac{1}{2}\Delta V_\lambda h  = \\
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \bigg(\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy = \\ \int_{\Bbb{R}^d \setminus \{x\}} \bigg(\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy = \\ 
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d \setminus \{x\}} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\bigg(\int_\epsilon^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g_t(x-y) - e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\Delta}{2}  g_t(x-y)\, dt \bigg)\,h(y)\, dy  = \\
\int_{\Bbb{R}^d} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}e^{-\lambda \epsilon} g_\epsilon (x-y)h(y)\, dy = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (g_\epsilon * h) (x) = h(x)$$

The reason we multiply by the  $e^{-\lambda t}$ term  is that it allows us to transform a scalar multiplication in a time derivative via integration by parts which gives us the time derivative on the Heat kernel.